# TeamCity Docker Build Agent For .NET 5

Tags: docker, teamcity, .net-5

Is there an official TeamCity Docker build agent for .NET 5? [jetbrains/teamcity-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/) seems to only support .NET Core 3.1.

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
```

I have searched [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=teamcity&type=image&sort=updated_at&order=desc) but cannot seem to find one.

Comment: It looks like the agent is using the .Net Core 3.1 SDK. You might need to build your own docker images, using this as a base, to include .Net 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a default docker image for .NET 5 but it's fairly easy to install it on the official agent image.

You need to get a bash shell as root.

```
sudo docker exec -u 0 -it <container_id> bash
```

wget needs to be installed.

```
apt install wget
```

Get the Microsoft packages.

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Install the SDK.

```
apt-get update; \
  apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```